# New home yellow and patchy lawn from animals

Tags: grass, compost, lawn-repair

If I thatch and aerate my lawn add some compost and seed will it help prevent this?

should I add tons of seed or tougher grass?[image][image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of animals  - dogs?